Resize a textarea based on scrollHeight
I have the following component in my project made with ReactJS:
<TextArea
  className="flex-grow-1"
  style={{ height: textareaHeight, minHeight: "40px" }}
  onInput={handleInput}
  value={message}>

This textarea has a minimum height of 40px, and as the user types, the textarea increases in height until it reaches the limit of 200px.
After that, the overflow is added so that the user can scroll.
To represent this, I created the following command:
const maxHeight = 200;
const [textareaHeight, setTextareaHeight] = useState("40px");
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

const handleInput = (event) => {
    const textarea = event.target;
    let newHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;

    console.log('newHeight: ' + newHeight);

    if (newHeight > maxHeight) {
      newHeight = maxHeight + "px";
      textarea.style.overflowY = "auto";
    } else {
      textarea.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    }

    setTextareaHeight(newHeight);
    setMessage(textarea.value);
};

The above command works perfectly. The only problem is when the user starts to delete the typed text, my textarea doesn't resize until it goes back to 40px.
For example, if the user has typed a huge amount of text, the resize will start at 40px, then 80px, then 120px... until it reaches 200px.
But as the user deletes the text, the scrollHeight remains at 200px (or 120px, 80px...), that is, it doesn't decrease.
I ended up realizing that the problem may be related to changing the height of the textarea, more specifically in the setTextareaHeight(newHeight) command.
Because if you try to remove it, the console message will follow the increase and decrease of the scrollHeight:
newHeight: 40 (user continue typping...).
newHeight: 80 (user continue typping...).
newHeight: 120 (user started deleting text...).
newHeight: 80 (user continue deleting text...).
newHeight: 40 (user continue deleting text...).
In this case, I believe that height and scrollHeight are closely linked.
So, how do I solve my problem?
